# jupyter lab: case sensitive text search

Tags: jupyter-notebook, case-sensitive, jupyter-lab, text-search

if type ctrl+f in jupyter lab, there appears a text finder, but the search is not case sensitive. How may I configure it to make an case sensitive search?